# GIT - ignore some checked in files in local environment only without changing .gitignore file

Tags: git

A lot of similar questions have been asked but I couldn't find an exact solution to this issue, we have a BIG project, with lots of other projects in it, the way the system is set up I have to check in the entire thing as there are dependencies all over the place.

The question is, there are some folders I do not want, as well as checked in node_module files and other project files, whenever I build intellij also creates a large number of junk files that I need to constantly delete / revert, otherwise running git add . adds all of them.

Is there a way I can force intellij to somehow ignore certain folders that ARE tracked, without changing the project .gitignore file, as that is not an option.

I found some solutions suggesting a global config, which I created and added node_modules in for testing, but they still show up as changed files in intellij (I actually confirmed that node_modules is in the project .gitignore as well, but they still show).

Any help is appreciated, I'm certain there is a solution that I'm missing.

This is a Java maven / spring project if that makes any difference.

Comment: `.gitignore` won't work for files that are already tracked. Most you can do there is either delete them (which is not what you want, my guess) or ask git to ignore them specifically with `git update-index --assume-unchanged file1 file2`.. that is a repo-local operation so that will work only for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to ignore modifications to files that are checked in.  Git doesn't provide such an option.

Some people will tell you to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --skip-worktree`.  This is wrong.  These give the appearance of working, but Git will still read the files in the working tree at times, so they fail to work with certain operations.  The Git maintainers don't recommend or support these options for this purpose.

In general, your project should have neither `node_modules` nor editor-specific files checked in.  `node_modules` is maintained by npm and contains code that's downloaded from the Internet, which you generally don't want in your repo, and editor-specific files are bad because different people use different editors.

If you want to ignore files that are *not* checked in on a personal basis, you can edit `.git/info/exclude` to add the patterns that you'd like to ignore.